# Unable to build AEM maven project because failed to resolve cndNames

Tags: maven, aem

I am unable to build a maven AEM project because of failure to resolve cndNames.

Failed to execute goal net.adamcin.oakpal:oakpal-maven-plugin:1.5.1:scan (default) on project *******: Failed to execute package scan. Failed to resolve cndNames.: Failed to find node type definition on classpath for cndName exportnodetype.jsp

Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're referring to is responsible for validating the content of your package against a predefined set of [node types](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/node-types.html).

Node type definitions can be used to restrict the structure of nodes in the Java Content Repository and they can be managed per instance. Some node types come out-of-the-box, such as `nt:unstructured`, `nt:file`, `nt:folder` and some may be specific to your project or a 3rd party tool you've installed.

In general, the content packages you're installing should only contain serialised content matching known node types. This is what the plugin validates as the project is built. In order to do that, the plugin requires a file with node type definitions, telling it what your AEM instance can recognise.

The error suggests that the plugin is failing to load this file. The [documentation](http://adamcin.net/oakpal/oakpal-maven-plugin/usage.html) describes the steps required to export node types and configure the plugin by adding the definitions as a classpath resource, e.g. under `src/test/resources`

If the documentation doesn't help, consider having a look at [the sources](https://github.com/adamcin/oakpal/blob/6037ccd937c6b9f2ed977e3be23ae1198602cd2e/maven/src/main/java/net/adamcin/oakpal/maven/mojo/MojoWithPlanParams.java#L120) of the plugin to understand what it does when it's throwing the exception.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, I will have a look into the documentation. @toniedzwiedz